# Selenium VBA code to paste data in browser

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to stimulate the control+v option in a text box in chrome using selenium vba wrapper. I tried using the context click but that function seems to click at a random position based on the cursor position. I tried using the send key function but i am not getting the desired result.

```
selenium.SendKeys (key.Control & "v")
```

Please any advise or leads would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You want to target the text box before using sendkeys. Let's say, hypothetically, that there is an ID called textbox1 for identifying the element then:

```
driver.FindElementById("textbox1").SendKeys("yourString")
```

Or

```
driver.FindElementById("textbox1").SendKeys Keys.Control, "v"
```

The latter assuming info is already in the clipboard with, for example, `driver.SetClipBoard "yourString"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better off using a variable to hold your data rather than the clipboard. Then you can use sendkeys to type it in:

```
myData= "your data here"
selenium.sendkeys myData
```

hth